# App name change

Tags: ios

Iam aware of the procedures to change the name of the app, my doubt is:
 -- Right now my app name is 'Anyvan'. Its an app that serves to transport providers. 
 -- Now we want to create another app for customers
 -- We made a mistake by not naming the first app as 'Anyvan TP'. 
 -- Now we want to rename the old app as 'Anyvan TP' and name the new one as 'Anyvan'.
 -- We are a bit confused and not really aware of any implications.

Once we do this change, will the old users who already have the app have any issues in terms of downloading?. What if the old user who haven't updated the app yet, tries to download the new one. Will it confuse anything?

Will apple allow this kind of name change ?

Sorry for my ignorance, this is one key decision, which shouldnt go wrong and a decision has to be taken at the earliest. If there are too many downsides, we need to go for a single app approach. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it needs to be sent to Apple support.

Comment: @Wain. Sure will do that if I didnt get any satisfied answer. The reason i didnt go to them first is that, a question posted to apple support is like a luxury one :). One two technical issues can be sent to them per year and anything more has to be paid for. I thought it would make sense to ask someone who already has the knowledge instead of wasting a chance. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @kesava, I provided you with an answer try it. I have done this myself in the past.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey.. Thanks for the answer.I am gonna try it. Iam not sure why this question has been considered off topic??. If someone faces an  issue and another one is even suggesting a solution, why would this be off topic?.

Comment: @Wain I know this is not about coding, but from when questions related to apple approval process are considered as off topic. This is a fairly complex issue and it needs some real world experience to answer it. This I feel is unfair. This is a genuine doubt i want to get clarified and I even got an answer from another person..

Comment: If we can get some evidence from @XCodeMonkey (or you try it and confirm success) that the solution does work then this question should be worth reopening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send an update to apple for the first app.

Within that update change the name to whatever you want. Then after that is approved upload the second app with the name you desire.

And no whoever has purchased the app will own that forever even when the name is changed. And yes apple will definitely agree with the change if it goes the way I described.

Comment: Have you done this before? Is the name available again to be reused by the second app immediately?